# Python For Loop Slows Due To Large List

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, psycopg2

So currently I have a for loop, which causes the python program to die with the program saying 'Killed'. It slows down around 6000 items in, with the program slowly dying at around 6852 list items. How do I fix this?

I assume it's due to the list being too large.

I've tried splitting the list in two around 6000. Maybe it's due to memory management or something. Help would be appreciated.

```
    for id in listofids:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "username", password = "password", host = "localhost", port = "5432", database = "darkwebscraper")

        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select darkweb.site_id, darkweb.site_title, darkweb.sitetext from darkweb where darkweb.online='true' AND darkweb.site_id = %s", ([id]))
        print(len(listoftexts))

        try:
            row = cursor.fetchone()
        except:
            print("failed to fetch one")
        try:
            listoftexts.append(row[2])
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
        except:
            print("failed to print")
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to close and reopen the connection each turn through the loop?

Comment: khelwood, I did that to check it wasn't the cursor object becoming overloaded, the same problem existed before this.

Comment: try moving the db connection out of the loop and use it in a context manager.

Comment: the db connection is not the problem i'm fairly sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it's probably because the list becomes large: python list are contiguous spaces in memory. Each time you append to the list, python looks if there is a spot at the next position, and if not he relocates the whole array somewhere where there is enough room. The bigger your array, the more python has a to relocate.

One way around would be to create an array of the right size beforehand.

EDIT: Just to make sure it was clear, I made up an example to illustrate my point. I've made 2 functions. The first one appends the stringified index (to make it bigger) to a list at each iteration, and the other just fills a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import time

def test_bigList(N):
    L = []
    times = np.zeros(N,dtype=np.float32)

    for i in range(N):
        t0 = time()
        L.append(str(i))
        times[i] = time()-t0

    return times

def test_bigList_numpy(N):
    L = np.empty(N,dtype="<U32")
    times = np.zeros(N,dtype=np.float32)

    for i in range(N):
        t0 = time()
        L[i] = str(i)
        times[i] = time()-t0
    return times

N = int(1e7)
res1 = test_bigList(N)
res2 = test_bigList_numpy(N)

plt.plot(res1,label="list")
plt.plot(res2,label="numpy array")
plt.xlabel("Iteration")
plt.ylabel("Running time")
plt.legend()
plt.title("Evolution of iteration time with the size of an array")
plt.show()
```

I get the following result:

[image]

You can see on the figure that for the list case, you have regularly some peaks (probably due to relocation), and they seem to increase with the size of the list. This example is with short appended strings, but the bigger the string, the more you will see this effect.

If it does not do the trick, then it might be linked to the database itself, but I can't help you without knowing the specifics of the database.

Comment: Okay, so how would I set an array of size '11533', add the text items to it and then convert it to a list afterwards?

Comment: It would definitely work with a numpy array (since you specify the size of each entry beforehand with "<U32" for instance). I'm not totally sure with regular lists.

Comment: I've pre created a list and the problem still persists. I'm not sure your suggestion works.

Comment: I've made an example, just to make sure I was clear. But if this does not work, then I 'm not sured what it could be

Comment: You're probably right. I solved it a different way however, which was by switching the machine i was running the experiments on to one with far more RAM.