# How do I match exact strings from a list to a larger string taking white spaces into account?

Tags: python

I have a large list of strings and I want to check whether a string occurs in a larger string. The list contains of strings of one word and also strings of multiple words. To do so I have written the following code:

```
example_list = ['pain', 'chestpain', 'headache', 'sickness', 'morning sickness']
example_text = "The patient has kneepain as wel as a headache"

emptylist = []
for i in example_text:
    res = [ele for ele in example_list if(ele in i)]
    emptylist.append(res)
```

However the problem is here is 'pain' is also added to emptylist which it should not as I only want something from the example_list to be added if exactly matches the text. I also tried using sets:

```
word_set = set(example_list)
phrase_set = set(example_text.split())
word_set.intersection(phrase_set)
```

This however chops op 'morning sickness' into 'morning' and 'sickness'. Does anyone know what is the correct way to tackle this problem?

Comment: You probably need to use regex, you can find **plenty** of resources on this online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice examples have already been provided in this post by members.

I made the matching_text **a little more challenging** where the pain occurred more than once. I also aimed for **a little more information** about where the match location starts. I ended up with the following code.

I worked on the following sentence.

```py
"The patient has not only kneepain but headache and arm pain, stomach pain and sickness"
```

```py
import re
from collections import defaultdict

example_list = ['pain', 'chestpain', 'headache', 'sickness', 'morning sickness']
example_text = "The patient has not only kneepain but headache and arm pain, stomach pain and sickness"

TruthFalseDict = defaultdict(list)
for i in example_list:
    MatchedTruths = re.finditer(r'\b%s\b'%i, example_text)
    if MatchedTruths:
        for j in MatchedTruths:
            TruthFalseDict[i].append(j.start())

print(dict(TruthFalseDict))
```

The above gives me the following output.

```py
{'pain': [55, 69], 'headache': [38], 'sickness': [78]}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using PyParsing:**

```py
import pyparsing as pp

example_list = ['pain', 'chestpain', 'headache', 'sickness', 'morning sickness']
example_text = "The patient has kneepain as wel as a headache morning sickness"

list_of_matches = []

for word in example_list:
  rule = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Keyword(word))
  for t, s, e in rule.scanString(example_text):
    if t:
      list_of_matches.append(t[0])

print(list_of_matches)
```

Which yields:

```py
['headache', 'sickness', 'morning sickness']
```

Comment: Hi Raphael, thank you for your answer! It looks like this answer works best for my case. I have one additional question though, my list consists of 74000 values and most texts that need to be matched are varying between 30 to 180 words. This makes it that it takes very long for the code to run. Do you know how to make this code more efficient / run faster?

Comment: How long is it taking to run? Is it taking longer due to the list or due to the parsing itself? Lists are very slow, if you can, use set() or dict()

Comment: Please try now with "pp.OneOrMore". I edited the answer. You can also split your list and use multiprocessing as last resort. Take a look at this post (about how slow it is to append to a list in python): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56719455/python-for-loop-slows-due-to-large-list

Comment: With a text of 30 words, the time with ZeroOrMore was 80 seconds and now with OneOrMore it is 30 seconds. The problem lies in the length of the list I suspect because when I make the list really short the code runs instantly. Do you mean I should try to change my `example_list` to a dictionary or set or should I change the `list_of_matches` ?

Comment: Change the `list_of_matches` to a dict() or set() (note that you will not have duplicated results in this case).

Comment: The time sink is probably not the time it takes to update `list_of_matches`, but the fact that you are scanning the input once per entry in `example_list`. You can create one consolidated rule (although with 74,000 entries, creating this rule will take a while) using `rule = pp.oneOf(example_list, asKeyword=True)`. Then you can reuse this rule for all the different texts (don't recreate it every time).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a regex using word boundaries

```
>>> import re
>>> [word for word in example_list if re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(word), example_text)]
['headache']
```

This will not match `'pain'` in `'kneepain'` since that does not begin with a word boundary. But it would properly match substrings that contained whitespace.

Comment: As Stefan says, how to deal with words such as "painful"?

Comment: Oops, needed a word boundary on both the front and back of the substring. Edited to fix this.

Comment: `example_text = "The patient has kneepain as wel as a headache morning sickness"` results in `['headache', 'sickness', 'morning sickness']`

Comment: @Raphael Technically according to the OP's problem description that would be the correct output.

Comment: Thanks @CoryKramer, this works for the example but when I try to apply it to my real list of 70000+ term I get `error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 55`. Google tells me to escape parentheses but I do not understand how?

Comment: I cannot help with syntax errors in your code unless you show the exact code, what line the interpreter is pointing to, and what the exact error message is.